# How do I insert Backoff script into my web scrape

Tags: web-scraping, exponential-backoff, retrying

I want to use the package "Backoff" in my web scrape and I cannot get it to work. Where do I insert it?How to I get "r = requests..." to still be recognized?

I've tried putting the statement into my code in various ways and it is not working. I want to be able to use this for the packages intended purposes. Thanks!

code to insert

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                      max_time=60)

def get_url(what goes here?):
    return requests.get(what goes here?)
```

EXISTING CODE:

```
import os
import requests
import re
import backoff

asin_list = ['B079QHML21']
urls = []
print('Scrape Started')
for asin in asin_list:
  product_url = f'https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}'
  urls.append(product_url)
  base_search_url = 'https://www.amazon.com'
  scraper_url = 'http://api.scraperapi.com'

  while len(urls) > 0:
    url = urls.pop(0)
    payload = {key, url}  #--specific parameters
    r = requests.get(scraper_url, params=payload)
    print("we got a {} response code from {}".format(r.status_code, url))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    #Scraping Below#
```

I expect to have the "Backoff" code work as its designed in the code to retry 500 errors and not have failures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling directly to:

```
requests.get(scraper_url, params=payload)
```

Change `get_url` to do exactly that, and call `get_url`:

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                      max_time=60)

def get_url(scraper_url, payload):
    return requests.get(scraper_url, params=payload)
```

and in your code instead of:

```
r = requests.get(scraper_url, params=payload)
```

do:

```
r = get_url(scraper_url, payload)
```

Comment: Hi - where would the "Code to Insert" go in the "existing code"?

Comment: you can insert it above the line `print('Scrape Started')`

Comment: Thank you! This worked I am very grateful and extremely relieved.